# Smoothing raster using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst

As you can see in the below result it is not fine.

I already tried tools like Majority Filter, Focal but didn't work for me.

All I want is to smooth a raster file and not having the squares too much defined.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to uses Low Pass [Filter](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/how-filter-works.htm#GUID-DF99C4E5-3A41-4107-9187-8FED8B76004E):

> A low pass filter smooths the data by reducing local variation and
>   removing noise. It calculates the average (mean) value for each 3 x 3
>   neighborhood. It is essentially equivalent to the Focal Statistics
>   tool with the Mean statistic option. The effect is that the high and
>   low values within each neighborhood will be averaged out, reducing the
>   extreme values in the data.

It can be accessed from `ArcToolbox -> Spatial Analyst Tools -> Neighborhood -> Filter` . Low Pass filter is the default filter type.

[image]

Comment: No point-able change.

Comment: What do you mean nothing changed. I used low pass filter many times and I always received good results. Sometimes you need to apply more than once to get good results.

Comment: There is only change in color Ramp i.e Black & White.
Tried 5 times.

Comment: What raster format are you using? Is it ESRI GRID, Geotiff, or something else?

Comment: I am using ESRI GRID

Comment: Load the output result from Low pass filter into ArcGIS, go to layer properties, then Symbology, and select unique values (if the pixel type is integer, and each pixel represents one class). Here, you should see the filter results clearly now.

Comment: When i combined the value or not (Unique Value) some how the result changes but the pixels remain same as it is(Square shape).

Comment: The pixels will always be a square shape. The result will not change the pixel shape, it will change the value. This means the low pass filter works well. raster data are composed of pixels and pixels are always be square. It  is not a vector layer that it will change the shape if you combined several small polygons. I advice you to study the difference between raster and vector data to get more information.

Comment: I know the result changes, But my question is how i can smooth the raster layer which look good.